# I am unable to deposit into a contract address deployed programmatically

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I am new to smart contract development, please what am I doing wrong in my code?
I have two smart contract (A and B) contract A is to be deployed by Contract B so that each transactions will have a unique smart contract address for tracking purpose.
but after deploying A via B, when i try to deposit some ether into the generated contract address from an account, using a deposit function declared in contract B, i get the following error. (see my code below)

> The called function should be payable if you send value and the value
> you send should be less than your current balance

```
contract A{

    address[] public owners;
    uint public numConfirmationRequired;    
    modifier onlyOwner () {
        require(isOwner[msg.sender], 'not owner');
        _;
    }
    mapping(address => bool) public isOwner;

    constructor(address[] memory _owners)public{
       for (uint i = 0; i < _owners.length; i++) {
            address owner = _owners[i];
            require(owner != address(0), 'invalid owner'); // ensures that the index 0 address is not an owner.
            require(!isOwner[owner], 'owner not unique'); //prevent duplicate of owner's address in the array
            isOwner[owner] = true;
            owners.push(owner);           
        }
    }

    function() payable external {
        emit Deposite(msg.sender, msg.value, address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

```
contract B {

A public contractA;
address public aContractAddress ;

 function initContractA(address[] memory _whiteListedWallets) public returns (address){
       
      contractA = new A(_whiteListedWallets);
      aContractAddress = address(contractA); 
      return aContractAddress;
    }

 function deposit (address payable _aContractAddress, uint _value) public{
        _aContractAddress.transfer(_value);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: resolved. for some reason i don't know of, writing a fallback function without the event emitter worked fine. that was my solution.

Comment: `address.transfer(amount)` are subject to a gas stipend of 2300 gas, if the fallback consumes more than that they will revert. A better option is to make a function payable, or not so nice use the `address.call()` instead.